# visibility hidden after playing animation

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add effects on modal.

I want to make like this:

- When `modal--show` class added, `visibility` set to `visible` and `opacity` continues to grow 0% to 100%.
- When `modal--show` class removed, `opacity` continues to decrease 100% to 0%, and after then, `visibility` set to `hidden`.

Showing modal animation works well, but hiding modal animation doesn't. When hiding animation plays, `visibility` becomes `hidden` immediately when animation starts.

How to set `visibility: hidden` **after** `opacity: 0%` with CSS or pure JS?

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/p1gtranh/1/

```js
document.querySelector('.open').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('modal--show');
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('modal--show');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0%;
}

.modal--show {
  animation: show 0.5s both;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  1% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="open">open</button>

<div class="modal">
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't add external links, use SO Snippet to reproduce the effect with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably scrap the whole animation and just make a simple `transition` instead.

In this case, `transition` is specified in a shorthand. The associated properties are:

`transition-timing-function: ease-in-out` - how the transition should be played, this value will play an easing fading transition when both opening and closing the modal.

`transition-property: all` - what property is associated with the transition. Since we are transitioning both the `opacity` and `visibility`-properties, using `all` will select both of these.

`transition-duration: 0.5s` - how long the transition should last.

**More on the `transition`-shorthand [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)**

```js
document.querySelector('.open').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('modal--show');
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('modal--show');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.modal--show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="open">open</button>

<div class="modal">
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```